# How can I use javascript, or css to make my text somewhat transparent?

Tags: html, css, text, transparent

I have a website im making where the background images change, i want the text to mimic the background's color but not so much where they are not visibile, how can i make my text transparent in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a font color of white on your text and you give the [text an opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/opacity), it will start to resemble the underlying color if it is very faint.  Here's one way that you could do it using inline styling (for simplicity) ([see jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/FEB6P/)).

```
<html>
<body style="background:skyblue">
  <p style="color:#fff;opacity:0.3;filter:alpha(opacity=30);">This is some text that will be partially see-through.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

As a side note, your website will be really hard to read.

Comment: Yeah i know...but the colors of the images work in a way where its not too bad and pretty read able, what are some other ways i can manipulate fonts as far as spacing between the letters go, etc...i need to use helvetica neue but it keeps coming out bold

Comment: You mean the default style of the font is too bold for your taste? Not much to fix that.  You could use letter-spacing in CSS though if you want to control the spacing between the letters https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/letter-spacing and boldness is set via font-weight https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/font-weight

Comment: what i dont understand is the font in programs like illustrator, photoshop...even word all have the font as ultralight, so why is it that in css it comes out as bold for the normal weight?

Comment: Are those programs using an ultralight version of the font and you are using a normal thinkness?

Comment: the "normal" in the programs are pretty thin, there is also an ultra light version which i like but i dont think css takes font-weight:ultralight; or at least it doesnt accept that when i type it in

Comment: Oh, sweet.... i tried font-weight:100; and it changed it to what looks like ultralight

Comment: would you by any chance know what tag i would use to use two different styles for two words in one sentence? I want to make one word a different color from the other

Comment: Use a span tag. That is the general case tag for separating things inside of a paragraph.

Comment: Yeah im using span but for somereason it doesnt seem to be changing my font to the right color, i want them to be white ive tried #ffffff but it still comes out black
<p> 
  <span style="font-color:rgb(255,255,255);
   font-size:300px; 
   font-weight:100;">
   kess
     </span>
  <span style="color:rgb(255,255,255);
   opacity:0.3;filter:alpha(opacity=30);
   font-size:300px; 
   font-weight:100;">agency
  </span>
 </p>

Comment: It's color not font-color.  So color:rgb(255,255,255);

Comment: One thing to note as you get better at CSS, you generally do not want to do inline styling as it is repetitive for both you typing it the user downloading the HTML page.

Comment: what do you recommend i do instead if i need to style a selected word?

Comment: if it's one specific word do it inline. but if it is one specific word many times on that page and other pages you should stick a class on the span tag and put it in an external stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Use a transparent color:

```
p {
  color: rgba(255,255,255, .5);
}
```